# How can I specify a Groovy CompilerConfig using Gradle?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have a **Groovy** project, where I would like to enable this **CompilerConfig**:

```
withConfig(configuration) {
    ast(groovy.transform.CompileStatic)
    ast(groovy.transform.TypeChecked)
}
```

How can I enable this using **Gradle**?

Comment: Not a solution, but [you're not alone](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/ability_to_specify_a_compilerconfiguration_instance_for_groovycompile_task)

Comment: I don't think it's currently possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle's `GroovyCompile` task doesn't currently support passing a `CompilerConfiguration` instance or `--configscript` option. See http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/ability_to_specify_a_compilerconfiguration_instance_for_groovycompile_task for a related discussion.

Comment: This answer seems to be outdated.

Answer (score 10):

Beginning from Gradle 2.1 it is possible, see the corresponding [release notes](http://www.gradle.org/docs/2.1/release-notes#groovy-compiler-configuration-script-support).

This is especially useful for working with [Groovy on Android](http://melix.github.io/blog/2014/06/grooid.html), see this [presentation](http://andrewreitz.com/getting-groovy-on-android/#/). E.g. you could add the `@CompileStatic` to each class with the following code:

File `build.gradle`

```
compileGroovy {
  groovyOptions.configurationScript = file("gradle/config.groovy")
}
```

File `gradle/config.groovy`

```
withConfig(configuration) {
     ast(groovy.transform.CompileStatic)
}
```

For more options, see the [GroovyCompileOptions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.GroovyCompileOptions.html) and [Groovy Customizer Builder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_customizer_builder).

Comment: Now if we could just get [eclipse-groovy to recognize that configuration](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/127)